# complex numbers and rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, linear-transformations, intuition

I have just learned that complex numbers and rotation matrices in the plane are the same thing (up to isomorphism). Is there any deep reason for this? Is it anything more than the fact that complex numbers encode rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I am looking for intuition and insight into the bigger picture if it exists.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose $\Bbb C$ is the even part of the Clifford algebra over $\Bbb R$ associated to the quadratic form $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: It is the same on the real line. Real numbers correspond to scalings and rotations (which are fairly limited on the line).

Comment: $$e^{i \alpha} \cdot e^{i \beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}$$

Comment: You should rather say that the *unit circle* in the complex plane is in correspondence with (orientation preserving) rotations. The set of nonzero complex numbers describes a much larger group generated by rotations and scalings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a discussion on [Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) or maybe one tailored to so-called [geometric algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) which is pretty much under the same umbrella.

Clifford algebra explains the connection between elements of a special algebra and rotations in a vector space (and more.) In particular, it generalizes what you see for the reals, complexes, and quaternions on $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ respectively.